# jQuery $.each loop and json mysql data

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json

Well i have this php for get the value of mysql.
I get two rows in this query.

```
include('../funciones/funciones.php');
$link=Conectarse();
$pnc=$_GET['pnc'];
$query="SELECT
accion_inmediata.accion,
accion_inmediata.responsable,
accion_inmediata.peligro,
accion_inmediata.ambiente,
DATE_FORMAT(accion_inmediata.fecha,'%m-%d-%Y') as fechaAccion
FROM
accion_inmediata
WHERE
accion_inmediata.id_pnc = '$pnc'";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo json_encode($array);
```

and this is my Jquery code

```
function traerAcciones(pnc){

      $.ajax({                         
      url: 'php_ajax/select_acciones.php?pnc='+pnc,               
      data: "",                        
      dataType: 'json',                
      success: function(data)          
      {

  $.each(data, function() {
 alert(this.accion);

});
      } 
    }); 
    }
```

when i execute this code the alert show me "undefined".
The $.each loop works fine  but the value is the problem.
Please help and sorry for my bad English

Comment: data is empty for any particularx reason?

Comment: set php page handler as json -  header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: go in your browser console, look for request in network tab and copy the response sent...show what that is

Comment: also...try alert `this` without `.accion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are returning the array of your first row only. So to retrieve both you might want to do this:

```
include('../funciones/funciones.php');
$link=Conectarse();
$pnc=$_GET['pnc'];
$query="SELECT accion_inmediata.accion, accion_inmediata.responsable, accion_inmediata.peligro, accion_inmediata.ambiente, DATE_FORMAT(accion_inmediata.fecha,'%m-%d-%Y') as fechaAccion FROM accion_inmediata WHERE accion_inmediata.id_pnc = '$pnc'";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link);
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array()):
$array[] = $row;
endwhile;
echo json_encode($array);
```

Now your jquery should be able to retrieve the data. Also, please avoid using `MYSQL_QUERY` it's deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass the value and the Index as parameters, this is how it works:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
 alert( value.accion );
});
```

Might also be a problem with the data object not containing what you think it does, do a

```
console.log(index, value);
```

inside your loop and a

```
console.log(data);
```

before the loop and you will see what you have and how to handle it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i get undefined too :/

Comment: with console.log(index, value);
i get
0 ACCION funciones.js:412
1 RESPON  funciones.js:412
2 NO funciones.js:412
3 SI funciones.js:412
4 11-11-2013 funciones.js:412
accion ACCION funciones.js:412
responsable RESPON  funciones.js:412
peligro NO funciones.js:412
ambiente SI funciones.js:412
fechaAccion 11-11-2013 

and with console.log(data); i get

Object {0: "ACCION", 1: "RESPON ", 2: "NO", 3: "SI", 4: "11-11-2013", accion: "ACCION", responsable: "RESPON ", peligro: "NO", ambiente: "SI", fechaAccion: "11-11-2013"}